# react native - how to play sound on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using pure js scrolling picker in React native and it works great on ios and on android :)

I want to add some sound or vibration to each scroll so it will be more user friendly

I did not find a way to do it anyone knows how it can be done and if you have any recommendation for a sound and source to download from?

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Responsive from "../responsive";

const Container = styled.View`
  height: ${(props) => props.wrapperHeight}px;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-self: center;
  width: ${(props) => props.wrapperWidth}px;
  background-color: ${(props) => props.wrapperBackground};
`;
export const HighLightView = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  top: ${(props) => (props.wrapperHeight - props.itemHeight).toFixed(0) / 2}px;
  height: ${(props) => props.itemHeight}px;
  width: ${(props) => props.highlightWidth}px;
  border-top-color: ${(props) => props.highlightColor};
  border-bottom-color: ${(props) => props.highlightColor};
  border-top-width: ${(props) => props.highlightBorderWidth}px;
  border-bottom-width: ${(props) => props.highlightBorderWidth}px;
`;
export const SelectedItem = styled.View`
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: ${(props) => props.itemHeight}px;
`;

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
export default class ScrollPicker extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onMomentumScrollBegin = this.onMomentumScrollBegin.bind(this);
    this.onMomentumScrollEnd = this.onMomentumScrollEnd.bind(this);
    this.onScrollBeginDrag = this.onScrollBeginDrag.bind(this);
    this.onScrollEndDrag = this.onScrollEndDrag.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: 1,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (typeof this.props.selectedIndex !== "undefined") {
      this.scrollToIndex(this.props.selectedIndex);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.timer) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
    if (this.props.selectedIndex !== prevProps.selectedIndex) {
      this.scrollToIndex(this.props.selectedIndex);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { header, footer } = this.renderPlaceHolder();
    return (
      <Container
        wrapperHeight={this.props.wrapperHeight}
        wrapperWidth={this.props.wrapperWidth}
        wrapperBackground={this.props.wrapperBackground}
      >
        <HighLightView
          highlightColor={this.props.highlightColor}
          highlightWidth={this.props.highlightWidth}
          wrapperHeight={this.props.wrapperHeight}
          itemHeight={this.props.itemHeight}
          highlightBorderWidth={this.props.highlightBorderWidth}
        />
        <ScrollView
          ref={(sview) => {
            this.sview = sview;
          }}
          bounces={true}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          onTouchStart={this.props.onTouchStart}
          onMomentumScrollBegin={this.onMomentumScrollBegin}
          onMomentumScrollEnd={this.onMomentumScrollEnd}
          onScrollBeginDrag={this.onScrollBeginDrag}
          onScrollEndDrag={this.onScrollEndDrag}
        >
          {header}
          {this.props.dataSource.map(this.renderItem.bind(this))}
          {footer}
        </ScrollView>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  renderPlaceHolder() {
    const height = (this.props.wrapperHeight - this.props.itemHeight) / 2;
    const header = <View style={{ height, flex: 1 }}></View>;
    const footer = <View style={{ height, flex: 1 }}></View>;
    return { header, footer };
  }

  renderItem(data, index) {
    const isSelected = index === this.state.selectedIndex;
    const item = (
      <Text
        style={
          isSelected ? this.props.activeItemTextStyle : this.props.itemTextStyle
        }
      >
        {data}
      </Text>
    );

    return (
      <SelectedItem key={index} itemHeight={this.props.itemHeight}>
        {item}
      </SelectedItem>
    );
  }

  scrollFix(e) {
    let verticalY = 0;
    const h = this.props.itemHeight;
    if (e.nativeEvent.contentOffset) {
      verticalY = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    }
    const selectedIndex = Math.round(verticalY / h);
    const verticalElem = selectedIndex * h;
    if (verticalElem !== verticalY) {
      // using scrollTo in ios, onMomentumScrollEnd will be invoked
      if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
        this.isScrollTo = true;
      }
      if (this.sview) {
        this.sview.scrollTo({ y: verticalElem });
      }
    }
    if (this.state.selectedIndex === selectedIndex) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({
      selectedIndex,
    });
    // onValueChange
    if (this.props.onValueChange) {
      const selectedValue = this.props.dataSource[selectedIndex];
      this.props.onValueChange(selectedValue, selectedIndex);
    }
  }

  onScrollBeginDrag() {
    this.dragStarted = true;
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      this.isScrollTo = false;
    }
    if (this.timer) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
  }

  onScrollEndDrag(e) {
    this.props.onScrollEndDrag();
    this.dragStarted = false;
    // if not used, event will be garbaged
    const element = {
      nativeEvent: {
        contentOffset: {
          y: e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y,
        },
      },
    };
    if (this.timer) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (!this.momentumStarted && !this.dragStarted) {
        this.scrollFix(element, "timeout");
      }
    }, 10);
  }

  onMomentumScrollBegin() {
    this.momentumStarted = true;
    if (this.timer) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
  }

  onMomentumScrollEnd(e) {
    this.props.onMomentumScrollEnd();
    this.momentumStarted = false;
    if (!this.isScrollTo && !this.momentumStarted && !this.dragStarted) {
      this.scrollFix(e);
    }
  }

  scrollToIndex(ind) {
    this.setState({
      selectedIndex: ind,
    });
    const y = this.props.itemHeight * ind;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.sview) {
        this.sview.scrollTo({ y });
      }
    }, 0);
  }
}
ScrollPicker.propTypes = {
  style: PropTypes.object,
  dataSource: PropTypes.array,
  selectedIndex: PropTypes.number,
  onValueChange: PropTypes.func,
  renderItem: PropTypes.func,
  highlightColor: PropTypes.string,
  itemHeight: PropTypes.number,
  wrapperBackground: PropTypes.string,
  wrapperWidth: PropTypes.number,
  wrapperHeight: PropTypes.number,
  highlightWidth: PropTypes.number,
  highlightBorderWidth: PropTypes.number,
  itemTextStyle: PropTypes.object,
  activeItemTextStyle: PropTypes.object,
  onMomentumScrollEnd: PropTypes.func,
  onScrollEndDrag: PropTypes.func,
};
ScrollPicker.defaultProps = {
  dataSource: [1, 2, 3],
  itemHeight: 60,
  wrapperBackground: "#fff",
  wrapperHeight: 180,
  wrapperWidth: 150,
  highlightWidth: deviceWidth,
  highlightBorderWidth: 2,
  highlightColor: "#fff",
  onMomentumScrollEnd: () => {},
  onScrollEndDrag: () => {},
  itemTextStyle: {
    fontSize: Responsive.font(20),
    lineHeight: 26,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#fff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    opacity: 0.1,
  },
  activeItemTextStyle: {
    fontSize: Responsive.font(20),
    lineHeight: 26,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#fff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To play sound on scroll you just need to use a library called react-native-sound
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound

in this library there are several actions available like

- **Play sound**
- **Pause**
- **Resume**
- **Stop**
- **Reset**

you just need to trigger required actions from above, when user scroll the page,
for that you can simply use ScrollView's props like

- **onScroll()**
- **onScrollBeginDrag()**
- **onScrollEndDrag()**

I hope you can get your desired result